# 'module' object is not iterable when running django website to the server

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, django-views

i wanted to run my django website to their server so i open cmd and go to manage.py directory :

```
 C:\Users\computer house>cd desktop/newproject
```

then i type this code :

```
python manage.py runserver
```

but i got this error :

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x03BE5A08>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\computer house\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 542, in url_patterns
    iter(patterns)
TypeError: 'module' object is not iterable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\computer house\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\computer house\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 120, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\computer house\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 364, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "C:\Users\computer house\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 351, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\computer house\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 73, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Users\computer house\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 40, in check_url_namespaces_unique
    all_namespaces = _load_all_namespaces(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\computer house\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 67, in _load_all_namespaces
    namespaces.extend(_load_all_namespaces(pattern, current))
  File "C:\Users\computer house\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 57, in _load_all_namespaces
    url_patterns = getattr(resolver, 'url_patterns', [])
  File "C:\Users\computer house\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 36, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\computer house\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 549, in url_patterns
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg.format(name=self.urlconf_name))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf '<module 'videos.urls' from 'C:\\Users\\computer house\\Desktop\\newproject\\videos\\urls.py'>' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.
```

and this is my videso\url.py code :

```
from django.urls import path
from videos import views

urlpatternes = [
path('', views.index , name = 'index'),
]
```

what does this error 'module object is not iterable ' mean ?

Comment: The concrete error means that at some point in the code executed by the runserver command it attempted to iterate over a list but it was a python module (which is not iterable). There is also a hint that the problem might be that the `newproject/videos/urls.py` did not contain valid url patterns. Please also add the contents of that file to your question.

Answer (score 5):

This error seems like either you don't have a `/videos/urls.py` file or it doesn't contain any valid url patterns.

**Step 1.** Create a `urls.py` inside your `videos` folder(if there is a one, no need to create)
**Step 2.** add the following code to `/videos/urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = []
```

Empty `urlpatterns` considered as a `valid` patter in Django

Comment: the problem i think was in this code in videos\url.py :

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with spellings
`urlpatterns = []`

and `urls.py` instead of `url.py`

Answer (score 2):

Two comments:

1. `urlpatternes`should be `urlpatterns`
2. In my case, the error was actually in views.py. So the python generated error message was a bit misleading because all of the urls.py files in my project were fine. I was able to get passed this error, once I commented out 90% of my code in views.py (except for a basic index(request) method). Once I had a working homepage, I was able to uncomment my code until I discovered the error.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps useful for someone else who finds this. In my case the error was being caused by an exception further down the import chain, there was nothing wrong with my urls (they hadn't changed since they were last working).

The way to approach an error like this, when the real exception is being masked by something else, is basically to remove all your urls and then add them back in one at a time each time checking whether you get the exception in order to isolate where it's coming from. So start by removing all but one url or url include, check if it runs, if it does then add the next back in and repeat until you get the error.

Then you can apply the same principle to your views, remove all and then re-add until you find the error. At this point you roughly know where your problem is so use the django shell (`python manage.py shell`) and import the view that you've isolated as having caused the error. This should give you the actual exception which will most likely lead to actually being able to approach the problem.

If just importing the view isn't enough you may want to isolate it into a test case where you can mock a request to give to the view but you shouldn't really need to in cases like this the issue is with the import since you're not actually running the view at the stage of just running your server.

Comment: Just realised I've mostly just restated Keith Ritter's answer in more words... oh well. Full process might still be useful for someone (:

Answer (score -1):

My problem was renaming typo

it should be

> urlpatterns = []

Answer (score -5):

If you are a beginner then, deleting the project and recreating it worked for me.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question.