# Trying to run a basic django code. When I run 'python manage.py runserver', I get this:

Tags: django

Just created a project, added app definition in settings.py, and created an app with a urls.py file seperately and tried to include the urls.py file in the main urls.py file that is created by default when we create a project and tried to return a HttpResponse in a seprate file.

Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sujit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 591, in url_patterns
    iter(patterns)
TypeError: 'module' object is not iterable

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sujit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 950, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Sujit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 888, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Sujit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Sujit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 118, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\Sujit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 392, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "C:\Users\Sujit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 70, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "C:\Users\Sujit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\Sujit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\Sujit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 409, in check
    messages.extend(check_resolver(pattern))
  File "C:\Users\Sujit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\Sujit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 408, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\Sujit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Sujit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 598, in url_patterns
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg.format(name=self.urlconf_name)) from e
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf '<module 'hello.urls' from 'C:\\Users\\Sujit\\Documents\\CS50\\lecture3\\hello\\urls.py'>' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.
```

Comment: Please don't just post an error; you need to post your code and explain what you're trying to do.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51576436/module-object-is-not-iterable-when-running-django-website-to-the-server/56047635 also please add your code as well, so we may see what might have gone wrong.

Comment: Got the issue. Spelt 'urlpatterns' as 'urlspatterns'.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error message is pretty clear:

> The included URLconf `<module 'hello.urls' from 'C:\Users\Sujit\Documents\CS50\lecture3\hello\urls.py'>` does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.

Make sure this file contains a variable named `urlpatterns`, and that you can succesfully import it.